# Is there a way to monitor data transfer per port on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

We are running a server process which has multiple active ports. I would like to know what outgoing data transfer is associated with each port. I would like to see a 24 hour report like:

- port 30000 : 2.4G
- port 30001 : 1.2G
- port 30002 : 2.3G

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) to capture the network traffic data per port.

`iftop` has a text mode (`iftop -t`) that may be useful - see [iftop - how to generate text file with its output?](https://serverfault.com/questions/379469/iftop-how-to-generate-text-file-with-its-output)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need a [Netflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetFlow) installation - a series of probes on the host that will collect the data about traffic passing and then pass it onto the collector (which may or may not reside on the same host), from which you can build your statistic reports. At the time of this writing the most up-to-date and functional netflow framework is [nfdump](https://github.com/phaag/nfdump). Since you're using Linux, the recommended probes would be [ipt-netflow](https://github.com/aabc/ipt-netflow).

There's also a number of derivatives/alternatives worth to mention, like [sFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFlow), but the most straightforward approach would be using Netflow.